# Encrypting a Secret String in a Prometheus YAML file

Tags: encryption, hash, oauth-2.0, prometheus

I am using OAuth2.0 in this Prometheus YAML file, and don't want to expose the client_secret directly in the file. Does anybody know how to encrypt another file with the client secret (client_secret_file) so that Prometheus can decrypt and use it?

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets: []

rule_files: []

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    metrics_path: "/actuator/prometheus"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8080"]
    oauth2:
      client_id: ""
      client_secret_file: ""
      scopes: []
      token_url: ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the solution **is** to use `client_secret_file` instead of `client_secret`.

While `client_secret` includes the secret directly in the Prometheus config, `client_secret_file` is a file reference to the secret, doesn't disclose the secret to a viewer of the file and the file should not be checked into e.g. source control.

To my knowledge, there's no way to encrypt arbitrary sections of the Prometheus config.